# Stored procedure returning correct results, PHP page not. Possible parameter truncating

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2005

I am inheriting this project from a previous developer and I'll try to be as descriptive as possible.

On the page, a user enters a search string and submits the page. The page hits a stored procedure, and the query returns back results.  The issue is when the search string is longer than 15 characters. If it is 15 or less, the results return fine. When executing the stored procedure manually, the correct results are returned. When trying to execute from the browser, I'm getting a false response.

First, the stored procedure and the parameters:

```
exec crm_selectSearch2 1, 'commonwealth water', 'PCBI'
```

Next the part of the query from the stored procedure:

```
IF @search_type = 1 BEGIN -- Organization Name
SELECT  org.org_name_1 AS name,
        org.org_id AS id,
        addr.address_city AS city,
        org.phone_number AS phone,
        org.email AS email,
        CASE WHEN ((org.org_status_flag = 'R' OR org.org_status_flag = 'N' OR org.org_status_flag = 'F') AND org.dues_category = 'MBR') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'member',
        CASE WHEN (org.org_status_flag = 'P' AND org.dues_category = 'FREE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'associate',
        CASE WHEN (org.delete_reason = 'OUT' AND org.org_delete_flag = 'Y' AND org.org_status_flag = 'C') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 'out',
        org.affiliate_code
FROM        organiz AS org
LEFT JOIN   address AS addr ON addr.address_id = org.address_id
WHERE   (org.org_name_1 LIKE '%'+@search_string+'%' OR org.org_name_2 LIKE '%'+@search_string+'%' OR org.org_search LIKE '%'+@search_string+'%')
AND     (org.affiliate_code = @affiliate_code OR (@affiliate_code = 'PCBI' AND ((org.org_status_flag = 'R' OR org.org_status_flag = 'N' OR org.org_status_flag = 'F') AND org.dues_category = 'MBR')))
ORDER BY    out ASC, org_name_1 ASC
```

END

When executing this stored procedure manually, I return a positive result. The previous developer wrote his own database handler:

```
$rpResult = dbStoredProc('crm_selectSearch2',$_REQUEST['search_type'],ereg_replace(' ','',$_REQUEST['search_string']),$GLOBALS['aPermissions']['affiliate_code']
```

The function dbStoredProc looks like:

```
if($iMSSQL = dbConnect()) {
    if($iResult = dbExec("select syscolumns.name as column_name, syscolumns.length as length, syscolumns.colorder, syscolumns.type from sysobjects inner join syscolumns on sysobjects.[id] = syscolumns.[id] where sysobjects.name = '".$sProcName."' order by syscolumns.colorder asc")) {
        $aArgs = func_get_args();
        $sSQL = 'EXECUTE '.$sProcName.' ';
        while(@$aRow = mssql_fetch_array($iResult)) {
            if(dbValidate($aRow['type'],$aRow['length'],$aArgs[$aRow['colorder']])) {
                $sSQL = $sSQL.$aRow['column_name'].'='.dbValue($aArgs[$aRow['colorder']],$aRow['type']).',';
                dbDebug('dbStoredProc: Attached "'.$aArgs[$aRow['colorder']].'" to "'.$aRow['column_name'].'";',3);
            } else {
                dbDebug('dbStoredProc: Failed to Attach "'.$aArgs[$aRow['colorder']].'" to "'.$aRow['column_name'].':'.$aRow['type'].'";',2);
            }
        }
        $sSQL[strlen($sSQL)-1] = ';';
        dbDebug('dbStoredProc: "'.$sSQL.'";',3);
        if(@$iResult = mssql_query($sSQL)) {
            dbDebug('dbStoredProc: Executed "'.$sProcName.'"',1);
            var_dump($iResult);
            return $iResult;
        } else {
            dbDebug('dbStoredProc: Failed to Execute "'.$sProcName.'";',1);
            dbDebug('dbStoredProc: '.mssql_get_last_message().';',3);
            return FALSE;
        }
    } else {
        dbDebug('dbStoredProc: Failed to Select Procedure from SysObjects;',1);
        return FALSE;
    }
} else {
    dbDebug('dbStoredProc: Failed to Connect to Database;',1);
    return FALSE;
}
```

If you notice right after the execution of the query, I am doing a `var_dump` on `$iResult`. The response is:

`resource(5) of type (mssql result) bool(false)`

This result is happening when I use strings longer than 15. If I use a string less than 15, the correct results are returned.

Am I missing something blatant?

Comment: Have you tried with multiple different strings of length <= 15 and different strings with length > 15? Maybe it has to do with character encoding or something alike?

Comment: The database handler removes spaces from the search string.

Comment: Also DON'T USE `$_REQUEST` specify either `$_POST` or `$_GET` as needed.

Comment: Nail - I have tried differing lengths.

Comment: Is it working with search string `'wealth water'`?

Comment: No, it is not working with `'wealth water'` or `'wealthwater'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
ereg_replace(' ','',$_REQUEST['search_string'])
```

removes spaces from your search string. So instead of looking for

```
'commonwealth water'
```

it looks for

```
'commonwealthwater'
```

The column `org.org_search` has all spaces removed, so it matches de-spaced search strings, but since it is limited to 15 characters (at least in the example):

```
'COMMONWEALTHWAT'
```

it can only match search strings of up to 15 (non-space) characters long.

Since the column `org_search` was probably created for a reason, and is possibly used in other code as well, the solution would be to recreate all (broken?) `org_search` values without the 15 characters limitation, and leave the de-spacing in place.

Comment: I removed the ereg_replace and it seems to be working, however I don't get it why if ereg_replace is in place, strings of greater than 15 in length are returning no results.

Comment: Have you tried the original solution with search strings of more than 15 characters *without spaces*?

Comment: I have tried the above `'commonwealthwater'` and no result. But If i try `'commonwealthwa'`, I get valid results.

Comment: <strike>I see. Can you check the content of `$_REQUEST['search_string']` when you post a search string of > 15 characters from the web page?</strike>

Comment: What is the length of `org.org_search` column in the database? I suspect that this is the one that still matches if you remove the spaces.

Comment: String entered: "commonwealthwat" - Result: `REQUEST['search_string']: commonwealthwat`.  

String entered: "commonwealthwater" - Result:  `REQUEST['search_string']: commonwealthwater`

Comment: `org.org_search` is a varchar(38)

Comment: What are the values of `org.org_name_1`, `org.org_name_2` and `org.org_search` for the entry matching `'commonwealth water'`?

Comment: org_name_1 = 'Commonwealth Water Treatment', org_name_2 = NULL, org_search = 'COMMONWEALTHWAT'

Comment: I assume `org_name_1 = 'Commonwealth Water Treatment'` and not `'Common Water Treatment'`?

Comment: Does it strike you as a big coincidence that `org_search` is 1: 15 characters long and 2: without spaces?

Comment: It seems very odd. But the it should hit either of the org_name, org_name_2, or org_search in my clause. I thought that was very suspicious.

Comment: I think my answer is complete now.

Comment: BTW: I bet the original code (with the `ereg_replace`) matches `'commonwealth wat'`, which is 16 characters long.

Comment: Thanks for helping me with this, Nail. Accepted.